# How to save scraped data from client-side browser to a user file? Use Electron?

Tags: javascript, file, browser, google-chrome-extension, electron

I want to pull data (maybe scrape) from a web site and save it to an external file.

My first thought was to write a Chrome extension to do that for me, but I could not find how to save to an external file.  (I am a newbie with Chrome extensions.) I searched StackOverflow and found answers:

"You can't do that in a Chrome extension.",  
"You can do it, but I'm not going to tell you how. ;)"  
"Use localStorage"

localStorage does not write to a user external file, and I may need to save many MB of data.

My second thought is to use Electron and write a special-purpose browser for the task.  Electron has node built-in, so saving a file is possible.

Before I put time and energy into doing this, has anyone already tried it? Any pitfalls or roadblocks ahead?

Comment: Regarding extensions, the authoritative source is the [documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/downloads#method-download): they can download the data to a file in the default downloads directory, optionally showing the Save As dialog where the user can manually choose any directory.

Comment: You don't really need a browser for that. A simple script (in any scripting language really) should be good for this task. If you want to perform queries on your file, you can either process it later with a different script or you can use Node.js and do everything in a single script; there are a bunch of libraries that simulate DOM objects for Node. Worst case you could even spin up a headless Chrome from Node to do all DOM related tasks.

Comment: The "download" will be text that I create in the browser, possibly from multiple web pages.  The documentation suggests that it is only possible to download using a URL, not save something created locally.  Or am I wrong?

Comment: @ErickRuizdeChavez Yes, Node looks a good way to go, and Electron gives a convenient framework to house it as an app.

Comment: In node you can do whatever you want, it is not constrained by the browser sandbox, so you should be able to do whatever you need. Obviously it is not as straightforward as just dropping some javascript on the browser.

Comment: For DOM manipulation/traversing in node I would probably use https://github.com/jsdom/jsdom.

Comment: @HarryB, locally created data can be converted into a downloadable blob URL or data URL. That's easy.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution. I'm having the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

I am posting this quick example as answer and follow up to the comments. If you want to test it, you need to `npm install request jsdom`.

```
const request = require('request');
const jsdom = require('jsdom');

request(
  'https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51896635/how-to-save-scraped-data-from-client-side-browser-to-a-user-file-use-electron?noredirect=1',
  (err, result, body) => {
    const dom = new jsdom.JSDOM(body);

    const comments = dom.window.document.querySelectorAll('.comment-copy');
    comments.forEach(comment => console.log(`>>> ${comment.innerHTML}\n`));
  }
);
```

The output must be the actual comments of this very same page.

```
>>> Regarding extensions, the authoritative source is the <a href="https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/downloads#method-download" rel="nofollow noreferrer">documentation</a>: they can download the data to a file in the default downloads directory, optionally showing the Save As dialog where the user can manually choose any directory.

>>> You don't really need a browser for that. A simple script (in any scripting language really) should be good for this task. If you want to perform queries on your file, you can either process it later with a different script or you can use Node.js and do everything in a single script; there are a bunch of libraries that simulate DOM objects for Node. Worst case you could even spin up a headless Chrome from Node to do all DOM related tasks.

>>> The "download" will be text that I create in the browser, possibly from multiple web pages.  The documentation suggests that it is only possible to download using a URL, not save something created locally.  Or am I wrong?

>>> @ErickRuizdeChavez Yes, Node looks a good way to go, and Electron gives a convenient framework to house it as an app.

>>> In node you can do whatever you want, it is not constrained by the browser sandbox, so you should be able to do whatever you need. Obviously it is not as straightforward as just dropping some javascript on the browser.
```

Answer (score 0):

[Ineed](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ineed) is a good start you can scrap text, images, hyperlinks , tags ...

```
var ineed = require('ineed');

ineed.collect.images.hyperlinks.scripts.stylesheets.from('http://google.com',
    function (err, response, result) {
        console.log(result);
    });
```

to write data and save you can use [FS](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html)

```
var fs = require('fs');

fs.appendFile('mynewfile1.txt', 'Hello content!', function (err) {
  if (err) throw err;
  console.log('Saved!');
});
```